# Creating a second Gmail account for support and to keep email separate

Tags: gmail, account-management

I want to create a second Gmail account to help contain some of my freelance/side work versus it all going to my main email address.

Stories like this http://www.zdnet.com/blog/violetblue/google-plus-deleting-accounts-en-masse-no-clear-answers/567  - where they are disabling accounts that aren't using 'real names' scare me. I don't want to create a second email account for side work, and then it get disabled.

The other account I was going to just have a name of xxxxxx.support@gmail.com where xxxxx would be my company name, etc. I was going to have the name as 'XXXXX Support', but would that violate any terms? And if so, where are the terms that force you to use a real name located?

Comment: I don't think you have any issues there. You'll only run in to trouble if you create a Google Profile with that account. Gmail ≠ Google Profile. That said, have you considered Google Apps? It's free for the basic version, which includes email.

Comment: Yes, I have used google apps, and thats the way I would go if I get a domain for this. I wasn't even thinking of getting a domain yet, hence why I was just looking at @gmail.com. And I have had an account for so long, you can actually make a Gmail account without a google profile?

Comment: I have several Gmail accounts. Only one has a profile.

Comment: @Al - if you make your comment into an answer, its the most correct and I would like to mark that as the answer.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you have any issues there. You'll only run in to trouble if you create a Google Profile with that account. Gmail ≠ Google Profile. (That said, have you considered Google Apps?)

I have several Gmail accounts. One I use to keep my gaming separate from my regular e-mail. Others a placeholders for my kids. Only my main account has a Google Profile.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using multiple accounts, use [this feature](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/1-awesome-gmail-tip-you-dont-know-about-seriously/) of gmail and filters to direct and tag your work messages accordingly.

If your main account is `bobjjones@gmail.com`, give your friends `bob.j.jones@gmail.com` and your business associates `bobj.jones@gmail.com`, and make a filter to put the tag `business` on the latter.

Comment: I thought about this, as well as the '+' trick - like bobjjones+support@gmail.com. The only thing I don't like about this solution is having my name/personal email address necessarily associated with it.

Comment: @jmlumpkin You could always approach the Gmail people with your conundrum (mailing them from another email address, of course, just kidding) and find out the fine-grained portions of the rule.  I didn't read that article yet, but I assume they are not creating these policies to combat people in your situation.

Comment: Good idea, and I did around the same time I posted this. Its sounding mostly like its fine.

Comment: i don't this is a good idea at all...especially if all is going to come in one inbox. First, it will cause confusion without any benefit. 2nd, You are still back at problem..keeping inbox free of other unrelated stuff.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer It never hits the inbox if you use a filter.

Answer (score 0):

As stated using Gmail doesn't require you to use your real name. If you decide to create a new account here are some tips I wrote before reading your question fully:

You can create another Gmail account and add your personal mail address as forwarding address under Settings > Forwarding.

After that you can log in to your personal account and add your new support address to "Send mail from another address" under Settings > Accounts. Also, tick "Reply from the same address the message was sent to." This will send a confirmation to your support address so log in to that account again and confirm.

Now you're all set and all mails will be received by your personal Gmail account. When you click reply the address the mail was sent to will be set as the sender on the reply.

Another tip is to create a filter that adds a "Support" label to all mails sent to your support address to be able to list them all easily and separate them from your personal mail.

If your company has a domain name this can all be done using Google Apps as well, letting you use a more professional looking support@company.com address.

Comment: Note to self: read the whole question before answering next time. :)